# c# date time format for SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

How do i format a insert statement with date time for this collation...

Currently:

```
string SQLst = "UPDATE [LASTUPDATE] SET last_update = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

This works for Latin1_General_CI_AS but now on a different server i need this statment to work with server set to collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

this is the error i get:

```
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value
```

Comment: As well as agreeing with the sentiment of Jon's answer (don't convert datetime to string), it's not the collation that's the issue here either - you'll find that the default language settings are different between the logins to the two servers, and it's that difference that's preventing the conversion from a string back into a datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be great if you do as @Jon Skeet said, but if you cant, than use CONVERT

```
string SQLst = "UPDATE [LASTUPDATE] SET last_update = CONVERT(datetime, '"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"', 120)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't perform the conversion at all. Instead, use paramterized SQL and set the value as a parameter. You should be using parameterized SQL for *all* your parameters, in order to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), conversion issues like this one, and to keep your code cleaner.

**Avoid unnecessary string conversions in general. They're almost always a potential source of subtle errors.**